# Is there a way to search for Greek letters in a PDF file?

Tags: pdf, search, unicode

There are lots of math equations that I'd like to search for (via Ctrl-F) in my PDF files, but copying them converts them to some non-descript text

Comment: Pssst... don't forget to update your question to let people know how you solved it! If you used one of the answers below, [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), otherwise, post your own answer explaining what you did. If you still haven't solved the problem, you can also [edit] your question to add more details about what you've tried and what hasn't worked.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, i have no problem using the Character Map in Windows7. Just copy it into the search field (I am using pdf xchange viewer). It worked 100% for me with a PDF full of formulas.

Answer (score 0):

It might simply be that the font that's used for the search text field doesn't support displaying those particular character glyphs. Did you actually try such a search?